# Laravel posting via API nested url

Tags: laravel, request

I using API resources with nested controllers, my urls look like:

```
GET /api/projects
POST /api/projects
...
GET /api/projects/:uuid/employees
POST /api/projects/:uuid/employees
```

I using also Request to save data per endpoint (for validation too).

The question is how to post data to save new employee (name, email, etc.) and validate and save value for `project_id` from URL?

Request rules:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'project_id' => ['required'],
        'name' => ['required', 'max:30'],
        'email' => ...,
    ];
}
```

My posted data has just `name` and `email` values and I would like get/set value for `project_id` from URL, it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prepareForValidation`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation)

```
protected function prepareForValidation() {
  return $this->merge([
    'project_id' => request()->route('uuid'), 
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Strange. When I merged uuid then validation passed, but not saved, I got general SQL error.

Comment: My fail, I forgot to add `project_id` to fillable array fields

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can merge or add project_id to an existing request.

```
  $project_id = $request->route('uuid');
  //Add to request
  $request->request->add(['project_id' => $project_id]);
  //OR
  $request->merge(['project_id' => $project_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to validate that a route parameter is required. a request without that parameter would not be reaching that endpoint at all. Instead if you want to check that the project exists in you db you can use route model bindings.

```php
Route::get("/api/projects/{project:uuid}/employees")
Route::post("/api/projects/{project:uuid}/employees")
```

now in controller, laravel will search for a project with that uuid and provide it to you or throw a 404.

```php
class EmployeeContoller
{
  public function store(StoreEmployeeRequest $request, Project $project)
  {
    //
  }
}
```